# Show total differentiability of $\phi: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n, x \mapsto \varphi(\lVert x\rVert_2) x$ where $\varphi$ is differentiable

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Let $\varphi$ be differentiable. Show that $$\phi: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n, x \mapsto \varphi(\lVert x\rVert_2) x$$ is (total) differentiable where $x \neq 0$.

How can I show this? I know that $\varphi(\lVert x \rVert_2)$ is differentiable by the chain rule but I don't know any "multidimensional product rule". How can I show differentiability instead?

Comment: I think all you need to show is that the identity map $\mathbf{x}\mapsto \mathbf{x}$ is differentiable and then simply treat $\varphi(\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert)$ as a scalar multiplier.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: Basically what I mean is if a vector valued function is differentiable and is multiplied by a scalar function that is "smooth enough" it should remain differentiable.

Comment: It's unclear, how can you calculate the value of $\varphi$ of a scalar $\|x\|$ if $\varphi$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Denisof The multiple use of phi here is a bit confusing I must admit.

Comment: @Denisof $\varphi$ is not defined on $\mathbb R^n$, $\phi$ is. $\varphi$ is defined as $\varphi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t see that these are different phi’s.

Comment: @K.defaoite Hmm, I don't really understand this argument, sorry. What does this follow of?

Comment: You should use definition it is straight.

Comment: @EDX How? I tried to calculate the jacobi matrix and apply the definition directly but I didn't accomplish showing that the rest function is $o(\lVert y\rVert)$...

Comment: Yes you need to take into account the $x$ in product.

Answer (score -1):

**Quick Proof**

We know that

$\varphi$ is differentiable. $$\|\cdot \|:x\to \|x\|$$ is differentiable everywhere except at zero.

By composition :

$$ \phi=(\varphi \circ \| \cdot \|) ×Id$$

is differentiable.

**Definition proof**

$f(x) \triangleq D(\| \cdot \|) (x)$ exits for all non null $x$

$\phi(x+h) =\varphi(\|x+h\|)(x+h) $

Yet

$\varphi(\|x+h\|)=\varphi(\|x\|+f(x)(h) +o(\|h\|)) =\varphi(\|x\|) +D\varphi(\|x\|)(f(x)(h) +o(h)) $

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your notation. What does $\triangleq$ mean? I have to show $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + (\mathrm D \phi) y + R(y)$ where $\lVert R(y) \rVert = o(\lVert y \rVert)$, not right?

Comment: $\triangleq means definition$ and yes I mean what you write :)